# Running a Node binary throws an error about "__DENO_NODE_GLOBAL_THIS_"

Tags: npm, deno, npx

I'm working on an ESLint package for Deno users. It requires both Node and Deno. Here's an example of its structure:

`my-lib/my-lib.ts`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S deno run -A

console.log(`This is my library`);
```

`my-lib/package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "my-lib",
    "bin": {
        "my-lib": "./my-lib.ts"
    }
}
```

I installed `my-lib` in a different package with `npm link`.

Since `npx` can be used for Shell scripts, I expected to be able to use it to run Deno scripts. However, running `npx my-lib` throws this:

```
error: Uncaught ReferenceError: __DENO_NODE_GLOBAL_THIS_1679791650__ is not defined
    at file:///Users/whoami/client-package/node_modules/.bin/my-lib:1:18
```

I can't find any documentation. How can I invoke a Deno script via `npx`?

Comment: npm docs: [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx), [package.json > bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) — deno manual: [examples > hashbang](https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.1/examples/hashbang)

Comment: I referred to the documentation while writing this and AFAIK it follows the docs' recommendations.